# Nexus IQ read password from --password-stdin

Tags: linux, nexus, sonatype

I am running Nexus IQ scan on linux environment. Is there anyway to read password from --password-stdin or anything similar? Our concern is the password is in clear text in bash history.

```
java -jar ./nexus-iq-cli-1.75.0-01.jar -X -i "APPGNL" -a ${username}:${password} -s ${nexus_iq_url} ${docker_image_name}.tar
```

Comment: Well, concerning the features of a piece of software, read the documentation and/or the code. Note that the password is not just in the user-specific shell history, it is also visible in the global process tree using tools like `ps`.

Comment: You can load from a file:  https://help.sonatype.com/integrations/nexus-iq-cli?_ga=2.26871421.130166431.1612798386-1730473862.1493385997#NexusIQCLI-LoadingParametersFromFileLoadingParametersfromaFile    And for extra security, you can use a user token instead of a regular username/password:  https://help.sonatype.com/iqserver/managing/user-management/user-tokens

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to read a password from a file. In your command, you can substitute `${password}` with `$(cat /password/directory)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 potential options:

--pki-authentication
Delegate to the JVM for authentication

https://help.sonatype.com/integrations/nexus-iq-cli#NexusIQCLI-Parameters

Or, this might work to hide the credentials. I'm not sure if they will appear in logs though.

java -jar ./nexus-iq-cli-.jar @cli-auth.txt -i Test123 -s http://localhost:8070 -t build ./sample-application.zip

https://help.sonatype.com/integrations/nexus-iq-cli#NexusIQCLI-LoadingParametersFromFileLoadingParametersfromaFile